# uninstal python 3.5.2 from windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, python-3.5

My python program was acting up so I went to uninstall it then reinstall it but whenever I uninstall it my computer says it doesn't exist, when I go to repair it or change it I get the same alert. I have tried installing it again but that doesn't work. If I even try to use python from a flash drive I get the same alert (the flash drive works on other computers) I just need to know how to uninstall it or fix it.

3.6 works just fine but 3.5.2 won't delete

Comment: "I have tried installing it again but that doesn't work." Why? What error message do you get?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error. It looks like it downloaded properly but then says it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check registry folders by registry editor *regedit*, as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxLd2R06BLw)